# PHP - foreach, use method return value or variable

Tags: php

Using the following 2 examples:

```
foreach($this->fooBar() as $foo => $bar) {
     // do something 
}
```

versus

```
$fooBar = $this->fooBar();
foreach($fooBar as $foo => $bar) {
     // do something 
}
```

Are there any implications of using either over the other or should readability be the only consideration between the two?

Comment: The only difference is that in the second case, you're keeping the result of the function call accessible after the loop, which both means you can still use it and that it won't be garbage collected. Other than that there's no difference.

Comment: ...and you use `->fooBar` in your first example and `->foo` in your second, but that's probably unintentional.

Comment: Consider also `foreach(($fooBar = $this->fooBar()) as $foo => $bar) {`

Comment: I would recommend against @AbraCadaver's proposal - it is less legible and is somewhat against a "separation of concerns", especially if you use it to access `$fooBar` after the loop. There's perl for that >;-)

Comment: @Archimedix: Not a proposal, a consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s basically the same.

In your first example, the result of `$this->fooBar()` is stored internally.

The second example only makes sense if you also want to use `$fooBar` outside the `foreach` loop.

To learn more about internals of PHP’s `foreach` and why you shouldn’t care too much about the difference between your examples (and similar other ones), have a look at the following article:

https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html